# how to validate captcha letters are not case sensitive using c# asp.net

Tags: asp.net, captcha

I need to validate captcha letters are not case sensitive in asp.net. give me 
some example ??? I have search but still not get any non case sensitive captcha in asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check This Link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/09/create-captcha-with-refresh-button-in-aspnet.html)

It will serve your purpose, as it only contains lower letters and numbers.

Or

You can choose you use your own captcha where you can choose only which characters you want to use for validation

[Check This Link](http://www.dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/6/create-your-own-captcha-image-generator-in-aspnet-using-c-net.aspx)

Comment: page reload means it automatically refresh right???

Comment: you will have a refresh button which will reload only the captcha using ajax